# angular 2 does not parse correctly html code

Tags: html, angular, unicode

Trying to HTML code to view the resulting HTML using the innerHTML property, but as you can see in the example below, it doesn't. The HTML code is viewed as the HTML tags and only, instead of creating the elements it renders them as  simple text.

https://codepen.io/Dralius/pen/OJzoZxm

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <span [innerHTML]='working'> </span>
   <span [innerHTML]='notWorking'> </span>
  `
})
class AppComponent {  
  working="<h1>hello world angular 6</h1>";
  notWorking='&lt;p&gt; Random Text &lt;/p&gt;'
  constructor() {
    // TODO: Define your Angular component implementation
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an idea can be to parse the notWorking string into valid html with domparser (for sample) before inject it in innerHTML

https://codepen.io/jeremy-denis/pen/rNpZKzO?editors=1111

```
const { Component, VERSION } = ng.core;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <span [innerHTML]='working'> </span>
   <span [innerHTML]='notWorking'> </span>
  `
})
class AppComponent {  
  working="<h1>hello world angular 6</h1>";
  notWorking='&lt;p&gt; Random Text &lt;/p&gt;'
  constructor() { 
    this.notWorking =  new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.notWorking, 'text/html').body.innerText;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, that is a good solution to the problem, i still cant figure out a reason OP would need to use the `&lt;` way to build their innerHTML

Comment: using it because it is coming from an old api that cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

This won't work just because of one little problem : It just won't. You are not using HTML tags, only the "symbols" of them. What is your problem exactly here? using `&lt;` is mostly used for printing out the literal symbol on the page, not as HTML tag.

Comment: isn't there anyway to parse it before passing it to the innerHTML ?